# create discrete step function in matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I am using the following code to create a standard discrete unit step function in MATLAB.

```
>> n = -5 : 5;
>> y = heaviside(n);
>> stem(n,y);
```

However, this prints [image] I tried lots of different variations and tried messing with the code. but I'm not able to create the function. Preferably, I'd like to have the function in a single variable so that I can do more complicated signal processing. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the definition of the Heaveside step function from the Matlab documentation.

> heaviside(x) returns the value 0 for x < 0, 1 for x > 0, and 1/2 for x = 0.

Note the result of this integral to see that the implementation is correct:

```
syms x
int(exp(-x)*heaviside(x), x, -Inf, Inf)
```

Comment: hmm, so I can save the result of the integral to use in more complicated equations?

Comment: of course, you can also use more complex expressions of symbols as the argument to `heaviside`

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I hope these functions will be helpful, the one you are looking for is the last one!

```matlab
%% Functions

function y=us(t) % continuous time unit step function

 y=(sign(t)+1)/2;

end

function y=rect(t) % continuous time unit rectangle function

 y=us(t+0.5) - us(t-0.5);

end

function y=tri(t) % continuous time unit triangle function

 y = (t+1).*rect(t+0.5) + (-t+1).*rect(t-0.5);

end

function y=usD(n) % Discrete time unit step, n must be an integer! 

y = 1.*(n>=0);

end
```

Comment: `+ 0 * (…)` always adds 0, which is a no-op. You can leave that part out. The `1*(…)` is intended to convert logical to double type. You can do that with the unary `+`: `y = +(n>=0);`

Answer (score 0):

Note that `heaviside` is defined in the symbolic library, it is mostly used for continuous calculations such as symbolic integrations, Fourier transforms and the like. You can use it in a discrete setting as well but whether or not the behavior for `x=0` is what you would need depends on the application.

Simpler ways to create a step function (without any toolbox) are:

```
step1 = @(x) x>=0;
step2 = @(x) (sign(x)+1)/2;

figure(1);clf;
stem(-5:5,step1(-5:5)); 
hold on;
stem(-5:5,step2(-5:5),'rx');
```

whereas the first jumps from 0 to 1 at `x=0` and the second one does it similar to `heaviside`.